# I call free(), but the pointer still has data and it's content hasn't changed

Tags: c, free

The code is below.

My question is about the result. I want to understand, why after calling free(p)
p->elem turns to '0', but the p->str still contains "hello"?

```
#define LEN (sizeof(struct node))
typedef struct node
{
       int elem;
       char *str;

}*p_node;
int main(void)
{
    p_node p;
    p=(p_node)malloc(LEN);
    p->elem=99;
    p->str="hello";
    printf("the p->elem:%d\n",p->elem);
    printf("the p->str :%s\n",p->str);
    free(p);
    printf("the p->elem:%d\n",p->elem);
    printf("the p->str :%s\n",p->str);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt1jf.png]

Comment: Undefined behavior doesn't mean "always crash obligatorily". I don't know why everyone has so high expectations of inherently faulty code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freeing memory doesn't actually clear the pointer or the memory it pointed to (except under specialized circumstances meant to assist in debugging problems like this -- never rely on the behavior though). Using a pointer after freeing the memory it pointed to is invalid, and is *undefined behavior*. It might as well crash, or cause random values to be printed.

Also, in C you should [not cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 1):

First, never do that in actual code. Your code works now only because the memory wasn't claimed by other allocations yet, and there's still a "ghost" of the old allocated struct.

On the actual question, your p->str pointer is pointing to a constant literal, i.e. a piece of text which is "hardcoded" in the application data. Hence, the pointer to it will be valid throughout application lifetime - here's a "more valid" example:

```
p_node p;
p=(p_node)malloc(LEN);
p->elem=99;
p->str="hello";
char* pstr = p->str;
free(p);
printf("the pstr :%s\n",pstr); // still outputs "hello", because pstr would be just a pointer to "hardcoded" data
```

Comment: dont need to use cast when calling malloc as it return void *

Comment: I'm just repeating his code here, the point is the const literal value illustration (`pstr`). That's why "valid" is in quotes :)

Comment: yeah,First,I want use GCC -S xx.c -o xx.s ,and try to vim xx.s .But I couldn't understand why assembly seems havn't change !