# C - free() doesn't delete my structure malloc

Tags: c, malloc, free

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    counter = 0;
    int size = 5;
    struct trie *mainTrie = malloc(size * sizeof(mainTrie));
    test(mainTrie);
    printf("%c", mainTrie[2].alphabet);
    free(mainTrie->alphabet);
    printf("%c", mainTrie[2].alphabet);
    return 0;
}
```

The test functions was just to see how I can use malloc. My experiment was successful except one thing: free(mainTrie).

When I added printf("%c", mainTrie[2].alphabet) after I 'freed' the memory spaces, the output still gave me the same letter that was stored at mainTrie[2].alphabet from method 'test'.

Am I not understanding something? Thanks in advance...

Comment: What did you expect to happen, and why?

Comment: `struct trie *mainTrie = malloc(size * sizeof *mainTrie );`

Comment: `free()` did deallocate the allocated memory. Your attempt to access that memory after it was deallocated has undefined behavior. Just don't do that.

Comment: @wildplasser: Yes. It's also worth explaining that the `malloc` call in the question uses the wrong size. It allocates space for 5 pointers, not for 5 `struct trie` objects. `malloc(size * sizeof(struct trie))` would also be correct but your `malloc(size * sizeof *mainTrie)` is equivalent and more robust.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801582/i-call-free-but-the-pointer-still-has-data-and-its-content-hasnt-changed and many many many other questions about the same thing.

Comment: I threw some stuff in the trash, but when I looked in the trashcan it was still there. Am I not understanding something?

Comment: Sorry, @KeithThompson ,it seemed too trivial, that's why it was only a comment. Any method of debugging could detect it.

Answer (score 2):

Show us your complete code, specially the maintree struct. It seems like you need to free the maintree variable:

```
free(maintree);
```

However, freeing memory means that the piece of memory you reserved will be available to the O.S again. It doesn't mean you actually set that piece of memory tu NULL. Edit: @MattMcNabb "Typically the memory is not released to the OS, just made available for further allocations from the same process. (This depends on a lot of things of course)"

It is possible that you are printing a piece of memory that doesn't belong to your program anymore, but the data hasn't changed yet.

Note these 2 important things from the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/)

1. **A block of memory previously allocated by a call to malloc, calloc or realloc is deallocated, making it available again for further allocations.** (just deallocated, doesn't say anything about the values being changed)

If ptr does not point to a block of memory allocated with the above functions, it causes undefined behavior.

If ptr is a null pointer, the function does nothing.

2. **Notice that this function does not change the value of ptr itself, hence it still points to the same (now invalid) location.** (so you maybe pointing to a piece of memory you allocated in the past, but it still has the same values, it is possible, it wont happen all the time).

Comment: Typically the memory is not released to the OS, just made available for further allocations from the same process. (This depends on a lot of things of course)

Comment: thanks @MattMcNabb for the correction! I agree with you.

Comment: Always incorporate corrections into your answer ... it's not enough to just have them in the comments.